# MVVMLight Simple IOC - dynamically register and unregister data service implementations

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a WPF application with MVVM Light Toolkit support.  The application has the following scenario.
The application has two Data connection modes. One is **WCF service** and the other is **Direct Database**. The application should connect to the Database through one of the above mentioned modes. The connection mode selection is situated in Login window. The end user can select one of the connection modes (WCF Service or Direct Database) and based on that selection a list of connection configurations are loaded in Combo box. (Please check the attached image for more information). The connection configurations are located in a local xml configuration file. Also I have a default connection configuration which should be assigned if any of the connection configurations is selected.

[image]

In the View Model Locator, I am registering the default service as follows

```
public ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

            if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
            {
                // Create design time view services and models
                if (!SimpleIoc.Default.IsRegistered<IDataService>())
                    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, MockDataClient>();
            }
            else
            {
                // Create run time view services and models
                if (!SimpleIoc.Default.IsRegistered<IDataService>())
                {
                    switch (DefaultConnectionConfiguration.ConnectionMode)
                    {
                        case DataConnectionMode.WcfService:
                            var wcfServiceConfiguration = (WcfServiceConfiguration)CurrentConnectionConfiguration;
                            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService>(
                                () =>
                                wcfServiceConfiguration != null
                                    ? new DataServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_IDataService",
                                                                 wcfServiceConfiguration.EndpointUrl)
                                    : null);
                            break;

                        case DataConnectionMode.Database:
                            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DbClient>();
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<LoginViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ManageConfigurationsViewModel>();
```

Both **DbClient and DataServiceClient implement IDataservice**.

If there is already a default connection specified in the configuration file, the above code works fine when the view model locator registers the view models at the application start.ie IDataservice is registered with the default connection configuration.

Now the real issue is when the user selects a connection configuration, that connection configuration becomes the default one and i want the MVVM Light to unregister the previous data service and register the newly selected one, and use it to connect to the data.

I tried the following code in the sign in button click and it failed :(

```
void SignInButtonClick()
{
        if(SimpleIoc.Default.IsRegistered<IDataService>())
                                    SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<IDataService>();

    switch (DefaultConnectionConfiguration.ConnectionMode)
                            {
                                case DataConnectionMode.WcfService:
                                    var wcfServiceConfiguration = (WcfServiceConfiguration)CurrentConnectionConfiguration;
                                    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService>(
                                        () =>
                                        wcfServiceConfiguration != null
                                            ? new DataServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_IDataService",
                                                                         wcfServiceConfiguration.EndpointUrl)
                                            : null);
                                    break;

                                case DataConnectionMode.Database:
                                    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DbClient>();
                                    break;
                            }
//perform authentication process
}
```

**Updated Code**

```
public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        public ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

            if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
            {
                // Create design time view services and models
                if (!SimpleIoc.Default.IsRegistered<IDataService>())
                    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, MockDataClient>();
            }
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<LoginViewModel>();
        }

        public LoginViewModel LoginViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<LoginViewModel>();
            }
        }

        public static void Cleanup()
        {
            // TODO Clear the ViewModels
            ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<LoginViewModel>().Cleanup();
        }
    }



public class LoginViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        ICometDataService service;

    #region Constructor
        public LoginViewModel()
        {

        }
        public LoginViewModel(IDataService dataService)
            : base(dataService)
        {
            service = dataService;
        }

        #endregion
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between `ICometDataService` and `IDataService` in your code above?

Comment: @tcarvin - Actually it is IDataService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simply remove:

```
if (!SimpleIoc.Default.IsRegistered<IDataService>())
                {
                    switch (DefaultConnectionConfiguration.ConnectionMode)
                    {
                        case DataConnectionMode.WcfService:
                            var wcfServiceConfiguration = (WcfServiceConfiguration)CurrentConnectionConfiguration;
                            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService>(
                                () =>
                                wcfServiceConfiguration != null
                                    ? new DataServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_IDataService",
                                                                 wcfServiceConfiguration.EndpointUrl)
                                    : null);
                            break;

                        case DataConnectionMode.Database:
                            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DbClient>();
                            break;
                    }
                }
```

from your ViewModelLocator and change the code in SignInButtonClick to:

```
void SignInButtonClick()
{

    switch (DefaultConnectionConfiguration.ConnectionMode)
                            {
                                case DataConnectionMode.WcfService:
                                    var wcfServiceConfiguration = (WcfServiceConfiguration)CurrentConnectionConfiguration;
                                    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService>(
                                        () =>
                                        wcfServiceConfiguration != null
                                            ? new DataServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_IDataService",
                                                                         wcfServiceConfiguration.EndpointUrl)
                                            : null);
                                    break;

                                case DataConnectionMode.Database:
                                    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DbClient>();
                                    break;
                            }
//perform authentication process
}
```

By doing this you only have to register your service once and you can guarantee that you're registering the correct interface.

Comment: I did. But it will throw an error while instantiating Login View Model property in ViewModelLocator. The exception details are as follows - "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation".Inner exception - Type not found in cache: DataService.IDataService."

Comment: Can you post the code for your login view model?  I suspect the problem may be that you're trying to unregister a class that you're currently using.

Comment: My LoginViewModel doesn't have any Default Constructor.So I have added one.Then the above mentioned exception has been gone. Currently LoginViewModel have two constructors Default one and parameterized one.While registering the LoginViewModel(SimpleIoc.Default.Register<LoginViewModel>();), I have the following exception:"Cannot register: Multiple constructors found in LoginViewModel but none marked with PreferredConstructor.". I have added the updated code block in the question itself.Please have a look.

Comment: If you have multiple constructors you need to add the PreferredConstructor attribute to the constructor you want MVVM Light to use when resolving the viewmodel in the SimpleIoc.

Comment: Thanks Faster. It's really helped. I will implement and get back to you soon...:)